# Replace a directory string with a ".." using sed

Tags: sed

How can I do these in sed?

```
#input                 #output
file.txt              "nothing" 
dir1/                 ../
dir1/file.txt         ../
dir1/dir2/            ../../
dir1/dir2/file.txt    ../../
```

Let's say #input is placed to $var1

```
sed "do something" <<< $var1
echo $var1
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do, here? sed might not be the right tool. If this is in a shell script, maybe you want `pushd` and `popd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this GNU sed

```
sed "s#dir[0-9]\+/*#\.\./#g; s#file\.txt##g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your test for dir1/dir2 (without trailing slash) correct? How does sed know if dir2 is a file or a directory? Otherwise you could use:

```
echo "dir1/dir2/file.txt" | sed s#[^/]*/#../#g | sed 's#[^/]*$##'
```